# Sign up How to test a method invocation inside an anonymous class using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

1.This is my code, I want to unit test it with `mock` or `powermockito`:

```
public class CarrierGroupDAO {
    @Autowired
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public CarrierGroupDAO() {  }

    public Map<Long, String> getAllCarrierGroups() {
        String sql = "select t.carrier_group_id, t.updated_by from  pv_carrier_group t where t.status = 'Q'";
        return jdbcTemplate.execute(sql, new CallableStatementCallback<Map<Long, String>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<Long, String> doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)
                    throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                ResultSet resultSet = cs.executeQuery();
                Map<Long, String> carrierGroups = new HashMap<>();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    carrierGroups.put(resultSet.getLong("carrier_group_id"), resultSet.getString("updated_by"));
                }
                return carrierGroups;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2.Following my test code:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetAllCarrierGroups() {
        CarrierGroupDAO carrierGroupDAO=new CarrierGroupDAO();

        CallableStatement cs=PowerMockito.mock(CallableStatement.class);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=PowerMockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        PowerMockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        PowerMockito.when(jdbcTemplate.execute(Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(CallableStatementCallback.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args=invocation.getArguments();
                System.out.println(args.length);
                TransactionCallback arg = (TransactionCallback)args[1];
                return ((CallableStatementCallback) arg).doInCallableStatement(cs);
            }
        });

        ResultSet resultSet =PowerMockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
        try {
            PowerMockito.when(cs.executeQuery()).thenReturn(resultSet);
            PowerMockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
            PowerMockito.when(resultSet.getLong(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn((long)1);
            PowerMockito.when(resultSet.getString(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn("haha");
            carrierGroupDAO.getAllCarrierGroups();
            Mockito.verify(cs).executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

**error information:**

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CarrierGroupDAO.getAllCarrierGroups(CarrierGroupDAO.java:27)
    at CarrierGroupDAOTest.testGetAllCarrierGroups(CarrierGroupDAOTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

If you have any idea to solve this problem,please to ask me ,thank you deeply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. You are mocking `JdbcTemplate` but you are not injecting this mocked instance into `CarrierGroupDAO` (this causes the `NullPointerException`).
2. You are using `PowerMockito` where `Mockito` will suffice.
3. Your `Answer` attempts to cast the secopnd argument to `jdbcTemplate.execute(...)` to a `TransactionCallback`.

They are easily fixed by:

- Injecting `JdbcTemplate` into `CarrierGroupDAO`

  ```
  public class CarrierGroupDAO {

      private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

      @Autowired
      public CarrierGroupDAO(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
          this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
      }

      public Map<Long, String> getAllCarrierGroups() {
          String sql = "select t.carrier_group_id, t.updated_by from  pv_carrier_group t where t.status = 'Q'";
          return jdbcTemplate.execute(sql, new CallableStatementCallback<Map<Long, String>>() {
              @Override
              public Map<Long, String> doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)
                      throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                  ResultSet resultSet = cs.executeQuery();
                  Map<Long, String> carrierGroups = new HashMap<>();
                  while (resultSet.next()) {
                      carrierGroups.put(resultSet.getLong("carrier_group_id"), resultSet.getString("updated_by"));
                  }
                  return carrierGroups;
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```
- Reworking the test case to use `Mockito` and changing the `Answer` implementation:

  ```
  @Test
  public void testGetAllCarrierGroups() throws SQLException {
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
      CarrierGroupDAO carrierGroupDAO = new CarrierGroupDAO(jdbcTemplate);

      CallableStatement cs = Mockito.mock(CallableStatement.class);
      Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.execute(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(CallableStatementCallback.class)))
              .thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
                  @Override
                  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                      Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                      System.out.println(args.length);
                      CallableStatementCallback arg = (CallableStatementCallback) args[1];
                      return arg.doInCallableStatement(cs);
                  }
              });

      ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
      Mockito.when(cs.executeQuery()).thenReturn(resultSet);
      // expecting one entry in the resultset
      Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
      long expectedKey = 1;
      String expectedValue = "haha";
      Mockito.when(resultSet.getLong(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(expectedKey);
      Mockito.when(resultSet.getString(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(expectedValue);

      Map<Long, String> allCarrierGroups = carrierGroupDAO.getAllCarrierGroups();
      Assert.assertEquals(1, allCarrierGroups.size());
      Assert.assertTrue(allCarrierGroups.containsKey(expectedKey));
      Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, allCarrierGroups.get(expectedKey));
  }
  ```

Comment: I love the Constructor injection advice (always a good idea, imho), but the OP could do without by simply using `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`, since Mockito can also do the reflection magic and put it directly into the fields. Also I would suggest simply adding an `throws SQLException` to the test case, since there is no real need for the try-catch block that makes everything harder to read.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz agreed re using `@InjectMocks`. Also, I have updated the answer to show a tidier test case, including an assertion on the response from `getAllCarrierGroups()`. I resisted doing that earlier because I was trying to change as little as possible in a bid to avoid any confusion i.e. I didn't want to leave the impression that the internals of the test case *had to be changed* in order to facilitate mocking `jdbcTemplate.execute()`.

Comment: Good thinking there, I honestly just concentrated on your answer, since it was basically all that needed to be said, so I just wanted to add some minor details and didn't notice that the try-catch was already in the OP.

Comment: this is great for me ,than you, glitch